# make the element be fixed at certain scrollY values in the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

please i want the element in my page be fixed at a given scrollY values.
the code

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<a class="brand" href="#">Goto</a>
<ul class="nav">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#andriodlabel">Andriod Apps</a></li>
 <li><a href="#movielabel">Movies</a></li>
<li><a href="#musiclabel">Music</a></li>
<li><a href="#pclabel">Pc softwares</a></li>
<li><a href="#morecontents">More</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

the css

```
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

please i need the jquery  so that when it reaches the scrollY value 200 it will become fixed...

Comment: Where are you stuck with jQuery? You should show your attempt, if any

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function () { 

    console.log($(window).scrollTop());

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
      $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 200) {
      $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    }
  });
});
```